# When clicked on Text field on WebView after clicking/tapping on Appbar, Webview reloads

Tags: flutter

If clicked on text field without tapping/clicking on appbar, it works fine,
but, when tapped/clicked on appbar(leading position or action position), the webview reloads.
with this error,
[ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(125)] Renderer process (4545) crash detected (code -1).

Reload happens when keyboard pops up.

how to solve this problem?

I'm new to android developing and flutter

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';

class ViewNext extends StatefulWidget {
  const ViewNext({super.key});

  @override
  State<ViewNext> createState() => _ViewNextState();

}

class _ViewNextState extends State<ViewNext> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  late SharedPreferences _prefs;
  late DateTime _lastRatingDialogTime;
  final GlobalKey _webViewKey = GlobalKey();
  Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
  


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initSharedPreferences();
  }

  void _initSharedPreferences() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    _lastRatingDialogTime = (_prefs.getKeys().contains('lastRatingDialogTime'))
        ? DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
      _prefs.getInt('lastRatingDialogTime')!,
    )
        : DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 7)); 

    _checkShowRatingDialog();
  }

  Future<void> _checkShowRatingDialog() async {
    final currentTime = DateTime.now();
    final timeSinceLastDialog = currentTime.difference(_lastRatingDialogTime);
    final daysSinceLastDialog = timeSinceLastDialog.inDays;

    if (daysSinceLastDialog >= 7) {
      await _showPlayStoreDialog(context);
      _lastRatingDialogTime = DateTime.now();
      await _prefs.setInt(
          'lastRatingDialogTime', _lastRatingDialogTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
    }
  }

  Future<void> _showPlayStoreDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('এই অ্যাপটিকে রেট দিন'),
          content: Text('অ্যাপটি উপভোগ করছেন? প্লেস্টোরে এই অ্যাপটিকে রেট করুন।'),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0), // Adjust the value as needed
          ),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('পরে'),
            ),

            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                _launchStoreRating();
                Navigator.pop(context);
                //Sent to Playstore and Close The Dialog
              },
              child: Text('এখন রেট'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
  Future<void> _launchStoreRating() async {
    final String packageName = 'your_app_package_name'; 
    final String url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&pcampaignid=web_share';

    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      print('Could not launch $url');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
        child: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            onPressed: () {
              _showPopupMenu(context);//for Drop Menu
              //_openDrawer();//For Drawer Menu
            },
          ),

          title: Text(
              'ন্যাশনাল প্রোডাকটিভিটি অর্গানাইজেশন',
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 15,
                fontFamily: 'bangla-font',
                color: Colors.black,
            ),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.share),
              onPressed: () {
                  final linkToShare = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp.w4b&pcampaignid=web_share';
                  shareLink(context, linkToShare);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<bool>(
        future: _checkInternetConnection(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else if (snapshot.hasError || !snapshot.data!) {
            return _buildErrorWidget(context);
          } else {
            return GestureDetector(
              behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  WebView(
                    initialUrl: '',
                    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                    allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
                    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController controller) {
                      if (!_controller.isCompleted) {
                        _controller.complete(controller);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ]
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  bool isTapInsideWebView(Offset tapPosition) {
    RenderBox? webViewBox = _webViewKey.currentContext?.findRenderObject() as RenderBox?;
    if (webViewBox != null) {
      Offset webViewPosition = webViewBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      Size webViewSize = webViewBox.size;
WebView
      if (tapPosition.dx >= webViewPosition.dx &&
          tapPosition.dx <= webViewPosition.dx + webViewSize.width &&
          tapPosition.dy >= webViewPosition.dy &&
          tapPosition.dy <= webViewPosition.dy + webViewSize.height) {
        return true;
      }
    }

    return false;
  }

  void _showPopupMenu(BuildContext context) {
    showMenu(
        context: context,

        position: 
        RelativeRect.fromLTRB(
          0, 
          MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + kToolbarHeight + 2, 
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 0, 
          16,
        ),
        items: [
          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap:(){
                          _showAboutDialog(context);
                        },
                          child: Icon(Icons.info)
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 6),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                            children: [
                              ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'NPO সম্পর্কে জানুন',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'bangla-font',
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  _showAboutDialog(context);
                                },
                              ),
                            ]
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]
                ),
                Divider(),
              ]
            ),

          ),

          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          _showContactDialog(context);
                          },
                          child: Icon(Icons.location_on)
                      ),
                      SizedBox(width: 8),
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                            children: [
                              ListTile(
                                title: Text(
                                  'যোগাযোগ করুন',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'bangla-font',
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  _showContactDialog(context);
                                },
                              ),
                            ]
                        ),
                      ),
                    ]
                ),
                Divider(),
              ]
            ),
          ),

          PopupMenuItem(
            child: Container(
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.black),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap:(){
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        exit(0);
                      },
                      child: const Icon(
                          Icons.close_rounded,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(width: 8),
                  Expanded(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(
                        'অ্যাপ্লিকেশন বন্ধ করুন',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'bangla-font',
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                        exit(0); 
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                 ]
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
    );
  }

  void _showAboutDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('NPO সম্পর্কে জানুন'),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0), 
          ),
          content: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 1.0),
            child: Text(
                '',
                textAlign: TextAlign.justify),
          ),

          actions: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: TextButton(

                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text(
                    'বন্ধ করুন',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void _showContactDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('যোগাযোগ করুন'),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0), 
          ),
          content: Text(
              ''
          ),

          actions: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('বন্ধ করুন'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _buildErrorWidget(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: const Text(
          'সংযোগ ত্রুটি!',
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0), // Adjust the value as needed
      ),
          actions: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {});
                },
                 child: Text(
                     'আবার চেষ্টা করুন',
                     textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                 ),
              ),
            ),
            ],
        );
  }

  Future<bool> _checkInternetConnection() async {
    var connectivityResult = await Connectivity().checkConnectivity();
    return connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none;
  }

  

  void shareLink(BuildContext context, String link) {
    Share.share(link);
  }

  Future<void> _launchURL(String url) async {
    if (await canLaunch(url)) {
      await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide some code or a snippet for context